# Lookup in Decision Table in IBM ODM Rules

Tags: xsd, ibm-odm

In Decision Table if i have ID's and i like to represent value's instead of ID's as LookUp in Rule Designer /Decision center.

how to build the xsd xom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution and helped a lot. By using `Domains` in `BOM Entry`, by locating `values`, `labels` , `verbalization` and `BOM2XOM mapping`

these steps can be done using many ways, i tried Excel Sheet and database:
for excel sheet:
view this link [Using dynamic domains for flexible rule authoring](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/bpmjournal/1302_rao/1302_rao.html)

For `database`, this article helps a lot it uses `xml` as a dynamic domain and you can re-implement it by extracting data from the database [business rule authoring in IBM Operational Decision Manager using an XML dynamic domain](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/bpmjournal/1308_delima/1308_delima.html) , by creating new `eclipse plug-in` project.